# How do I convert a file's format from Unicode to ASCII using Python?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, file, ascii

I use a 3rd party tool that outputs a file in Unicode format.  However, I prefer it to be in ASCII. The tool does not have settings to change the file format.

What is the best way to convert the entire file format using Python?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can convert the file easily enough just using the `unicode` function, but you'll run into problems with Unicode characters without a straight ASCII equivalent.

[This blog](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/unicode-to-ascii) recommends the `unicodedata`  module, which seems to take care of roughly converting characters without direct corresponding ASCII values, e.g.

```
>>> title = u"Klüft skräms inför på fédéral électoral große"
```

is typically converted to

```
Klft skrms infr p fdral lectoral groe
```

which is pretty wrong. However, using the `unicodedata` module, the result can be much closer to the original text:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', title).encode('ascii','ignore')
'Kluft skrams infor pa federal electoral groe'
```

Comment: That one's pretty good, except (as noted) it misses a few characters.  For Latin-1, you need to special-case Æ, Ð, Ø, Þ, æ, ð, ø, ß, and þ.

Comment: Fredrick Lundh posted on this, with a simple script to build on top of `unicodedata` for special-case replacements: http://effbot.org/zone/unicode-convert.htm

Answer (score 11):

*I think this is a deeper issue than you realize*. Simply changing the file from Unicode into ASCII is easy, however, getting all of the Unicode characters to translate into reasonable ASCII counterparts (many letters are not available in both encodings) is another.

This Python Unicode tutorial may give you a better idea of what happens to Unicode strings that are translated to ASCII: http://www.reportlab.com/i18n/python_unicode_tutorial.html

**Here's a useful quote from the site:**

> Python 1.6 also gets a "unicode"
>   built-in function, to which you can
>   specify the encoding:

```
> >>> unicode('hello') u'hello'
> >>> unicode('hello', 'ascii') u'hello'
> >>> unicode('hello', 'iso-8859-1') u'hello'
> >>>
```

> All three of these return the same
>   thing, since the characters in 'Hello'
>   are common to all three encodings.
>
> Now let's encode something with a
>   European accent, which is outside of
>   ASCII. What you see at a console may
>   depend on your operating system
>   locale; Windows lets me type in
>   ISO-Latin-1.

```
> >>> a = unicode('André','latin-1')
> >>> a u'Andr\202'
```

> If you can't type an acute letter e,
>   you can enter the string 'Andr\202',
>   which is unambiguous.
>
> Unicode supports all the common
>   operations such as iteration and
>   splitting. We won't run over them
>   here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the potential problems. However, I do not run the risk of having non-convertible unicode characters within the content of output file. It is just outputting the SQL schema of an internal database and does not contain any characters out of the ordinary i.e. beyond ASCII.

Comment: @Ray Vega: That you know of right now.  It's a mistake and potential bug to assume that unicode data will only ever have ASCII characters.

Answer (score 4):

By the way, these is a linux command `iconv` to do this kind of job.

```
iconv -f utf8 -t ascii <input.txt >output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
uc = open(filename).read().decode('utf8')
ascii = uc.decode('ascii')
```

Note, however, that this will **fail** with a `UnicodeDecodeError` exception if there are any characters that can't be converted to ASCII.

EDIT: As Pete Karl just pointed out, there is no one-to-one mapping from Unicode to ASCII.  So some characters simply can't be converted in an information-preserving way.  Moreover, standard ASCII is more or less a subset of UTF-8, so you don't really even need to do any decoding.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some simple (and stupid) code to do encoding translation.  I'm assuming (but you shouldn't) that the input file is in UTF-16 (Windows calls this simply 'Unicode').

```
input_codec = 'UTF-16'
output_codec = 'ASCII'

unicode_file = open('filename')
unicode_data = unicode_file.read().decode(input_codec)
ascii_file = open('new filename', 'w')
ascii_file.write(unicode_data.write(unicode_data.encode(output_codec)))
```

Note that this will not work if there are any characters in the Unicode file that are not also ASCII characters.  You can do the following to turn unrecognized characters into '?'s:

```
ascii_file.write(unicode_data.write(unicode_data.encode(output_codec, 'replace')))
```

Check out [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) for more simple choices.  If you need to do anything more sophisticated, you may wish to check out [The UNICODE Hammer](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/251871/) at the Python Cookbook.

Answer (score 2):

For my problem where I just wanted to skip the Non-ascii characters and just output only ascii output, the below solution worked really well:

```
    import unicodedata
    input = open(filename).read().decode('UTF-16')
    output = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input).encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that there is no 'Unicode' file format.  Unicode can be encoded to bytes in several different ways.  Most commonly UTF-8 or UTF-16.  You'll need to know which one your 3rd-party tool is outputting.  Once you know that, converting between different encodings is pretty easy:

```
in_file = open("myfile.txt", "rb")
out_file = open("mynewfile.txt", "wb")

in_byte_string = in_file.read()
unicode_string = bytestring.decode('UTF-16')
out_byte_string = unicode_string.encode('ASCII')

out_file.write(out_byte_string)
out_file.close()
```

As noted in the other replies, you're probably going to want to supply an error handler to the encode method.  Using 'replace' as the error handler is simple, but will mangle your text if it contains characters that cannot be represented in ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

As other posters have noted, ASCII is a subset of unicode.

However if you:

- have a legacy app
- you don't control the code for that app
- you're sure your input falls into the ASCII subset

Then the example below shows how to do it:

```
mystring = u'bar'
type(mystring)
    <type 'unicode'>

myasciistring = (mystring.encode('ASCII'))
type(myasciistring)
    <type 'str'>
```