# graphml generate from my application cannot open on yEd Graph Editor

Tags: delphi-7, graphml

I generate graphml file from my application writing in Delphi7. Every thing is fine except when I open some my graphml file using yEd Graph Editor It raise Error like this.

```
test.graphml.
    at B.A.A.I.A.ā(Unknown Source)
    at B.A.A.I.D.ā(Unknown Source)
    at B.A.A.I.D.ă(Unknown Source)
    at B.A.A.B$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at B.A.A.U.Ċ(Unknown Source)
    at B.A.A.U$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: D.H.B.B.a: IOException :Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at D.H.B.B._.ā(Unknown Source)
    at D.H.B.A$13.ā(Unknown Source)
    at D.H.B.A.ā(Unknown Source)
    at D.H.B.A.ā(Unknown Source)
    at D.H.S.ā(Unknown Source)
    at B.A.A.I.A.A.ā(Unknown Source)
    at B.A.A.B.I.O.Ă(Unknown Source)
    at B.A.A.B.I.O.ā(Unknown Source)
    at B.A.A.O.E.ā(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.peekChar(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
```

How I solved this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem should come from Unicode [invalid bytes sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences) problem but without your file I can only guess.

I think you may load string from non-Unicode encoding file and use it directly without convert to Unicode encoding. Please try convert these strings to Unicode by see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305162/how-can-i-convert-unicode-characters-to-ascii-codes-in-delphi-7).