# losing characters when going from unicode to ascii

Tags: python, django

y0 I have this problem that characters that include ñ or ŕ í á ú etc are discarded when I apply

```
text = text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

to a function that needs the input to be ascii.

is there a way to force it to ascii without losing those characters or should I change the function to accept unicode characters?

http://dpaste.com/601417/

Comment: What function? Why does it "need the input to be ascii"?

Comment: Use normalization, then throw away the diacritics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175240/how-do-i-convert-a-files-format-from-unicode-to-ascii-using-python/175270#175270

Answer (score 5):

The `'ascii'` encoding can't represent the characters you refer to. You have to choose a different encoding — perhaps `'cp850'` or `'latin_1'` — but then you have to be sure that your output terminal interprets 8-bit codes using the relevant code page.

On balance, life is easier if you just go Unicode all the way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should go for another encoding, if you need those characters (for example Unicode). See [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for all chars that are included in ascii.