# Python reads data as binary strings instead of text from log file

Tags: python, file, text

I have a file with computer logs. When I open it in notepad++, the first few lines look like this -

```
#####################
[2015/07/03, 13:26:40.368,  INFO, 00004588] Legacy mode. Epoch number not found. Allowing message.
[2015/07/03, 13:26:40.368,  INFO, 00004588] >>>AgentGetState() called.
[2015/07/03, 13:26:40.368,  INFO, 00004588] AgentGetState Returning 00000000.<<<
[2015/07/03, 13:26:54.660,  INFO, 00010404] Subject name = am4prdapp09.fc.core.windows.net
[2015/07/03, 13:26:54.660,  INFO, 00010404] Legacy mode. Epoch number not found. Allowing message.
######################
```

Now, I read them in python like so -

```
f = open("log_file.log")
a = []
for i in f:
    a.append(i)
```

When I now look at the content:

```
a[0]
```

This is what I see -

```
'\xff\xfe[\x002\x000\x001\x005\x00/\x000\x007\x00/\x000\x003\x00,\x00 \x001\x003\x00:\x002\x006\x00:\x004\x000\x00.\x003\x006\x008\x00,\x00 \x00 \x00I\x00N\x00F\x00O\x00,\x00 \x000\x000\x000\x000\x004\x005\x008\x008\x00]\x00 \x00
\x00j\x00e\x00c\x00t\x00 \x00n\x00a\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00=\x00 \x00a\x00m\x004\x00p\x00r\x00d\x00a\x00p\x00p\x000\x009\x00.\x00f\x00c\x00.\x00c\x00o\x00r\x00e\x00.\x00w\x00i\x00n\x00d\x00o\x00w\x00s\x00.\x00n\x00e\x00t\x00\r\x00\n'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What's the encoding of the file?

Comment: and your python version?

Comment: Works fine for me... `a[0]` = `#####################`

Comment: On an unrelated side note, `a = list(f)` would do the trick without your 3-line for loop there.

Comment: @MaxNoe - Unicode. I guess I need to convert it to ASCII. I'll try and do that. Thanks.

Comment: @FGFW - Its python 2.7 with Anaconda. I tried to convert Unicode string to text using code here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175240/how-do-i-convert-a-files-format-from-unicode-to-ascii-using-python and some other places but no luck so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
f = open("log_file.log", 'r')
data = f.readlines()
for i in data:
    print i
>>> line
>>> ...
>>> ...
```

Comment: You should use `with open ...`

Comment: Python's file objects are iterable to begin with. You should do `for i in f` (or more descriptively, `for line in f`). The only reason to call `readlines()` first is if you just want to eat the cost of front-loading the whole thing into memory.